# Closest point on Bézier spline

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, curves, splines

Given a two-dimensional cubic Bézier spline defined by 4 control-points as described in [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves), is there a way to solve analytically for the parameter along the curve (ranging from 0 to 1) which yields the point closest to an arbitrary point in space?

$$
\mathbf{B}(t) = (1-t)^3 \,\mathbf{P}_0 + 3(1-t)^2 t\,\mathbf{P}_1 + 3(1-t) t^2\,\mathbf{P}_2 + t^3\,\mathbf{P}_3, ~~~~~  t \in [0,1]
$$
where $\mathbf P_0$, $\mathbf P_1$, $\mathbf P_2$, and $\mathbf P_3$ are the four control-points of the curve.

I can solve it pretty reliably and quickly with a divide-and-conquer algorithm, but it makes me feel dirty…

Comment: You may have more luck with this kind of question in the places mentioned in the FAQ: http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot

Comment: A reliable and fast numerical algorithm is your best bet. Analytic solutions, even if they exist (which I doubt in this case), are not always the best choice. Even finding the roots of a cubic polynomial with Cardano's formula is messy and numerically unstable.

Comment: Thanks lhf. Suppose I'll stick with my current solution then.

Comment: If you want to see an implementation of calculating the distance from one point to a Bezier Curve(the closest point) , you can check out the "Runtime Curve Editor" https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11835 ,
that's an Unity package(you perhaps need to install Unity) ,all the code is available,is C#,but math is the same, the package is doing much more than just calculating that distance(projection) , the price of package is 45$.

Comment: Which algorithm does it use, for those of us who do not have 45$ to spare?

Comment: I don't see a mention here of the fact that cubic Bezier splines can intersect themselves (at most once I think).  Looks like if one marks values of t where either x(t) or y(t) hits a local minimum or maximum, then draws a stick figure of the curve, one can find whether and which two monotonic sections of curve intersect.

Comment: Oops, crossing sticks can get false positives but not false negatives.  To make sure a positive is true, enclose each curve segment in a triangle with one side being the "stick" between the curve segment's end points.  If the sticks pierce all the way thru each other's triangle, there's an intersection.  If the sticks cross and stick A's end is inside triangle B, check whether stick a crosses curve B.  Erm, easy peasy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a Bézier curve $(x(t),y(t))$, the closest point to the origin (say) is given by the minimum of $f(t) = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2$.  By calculus, this minimum is either at the endpoints or when the derivative vanishes, $f'(t) = 0$.  This latter condition is evidently a quintic polynomial.  Now, there is no exact formula in radicals for solving the quintic.  However, there is a really nifty new iterative algorithm based on the symmetry group of the icosahedron due to Doyle and McMullen ([Solving the quintic by integration](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Edoyle/docs/icos/icos.pdf)).  They make the point that you use a dynamical iteration anyway to find radicals via Newton's method; if you think of a quintic equation as a generalized radical, then it has an iteration that it just as robust numerically as finding radicals with Newton's method.

Contrary to what lhf [said](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8983/closest-point-on-bezier-spline#comment12433_8983), Cardano's formula for the cubic polynomial is perfectly stable numerically.  You just need arithmetic with complex numbers even if, indeed exactly when, all three roots are real.

There is also a more ordinary approach to finding real roots of a quintic polynomial.  (Like Cardano's formula, the Doyle–McMullen solution requires complex numbers and finds the complex roots equally easily.)  Namely, you can use a cutoff procedure to switch from divide-and-conquer to Newton's method.  For example, if your quintic $q(x)$ on a unit interval $[0,1]$ is $40-100x+x^5$, then it is clearly close enough to linear that Newton's method will work; you don't need divide-and-conquer.  So if you have cut down the solution space to any interval, you can change the interval to $[0,1]$ (or maybe better $[-1,1]$), and then in the new variable decide whether the norms of the coefficients guarantee that Newton's method will converge.  This method should only make you feel "a little dirty", because for general high-degree polynomials it's a competitive numerical algorithm.  (Higher than quintic, maybe; Doyle–McMullen is really pretty good.)

See also the related MO question [Can Gröbner bases be used to compute solutions to large, real-world problems?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5760/can-grobner-bases-be-used-to-compute-solutions-to-large-real-world-problems) on the multivariate situation, which you would encounter for bicubic patches in 3D.  The multivariate situation is pretty much the same:  You have a choice between polynomial algebra and divide-and-conquer plus Newton's method.  The higher the dimension, the more justification there is for the latter over the former.

Comment: Perhaps I was too harsh. I meant this: http://linus.socs.uts.edu.au/~don/pubs/solving.html

Comment: That is an interesting analysis that could well be useful for high-performance graphics software.  However, the author mentions in passing that you can clean up any rounding problems with a single Newton's method step at the end.  Good enough for government work.


Answer (score 0):

```
t=0
while p(t) is not close enough:
  compute a line based on v(t)
  t = time of closest point on the line to the target (perpendicular)
```

This seems to converge quite rapidly. Just a few iterations gives a nice approximation. Works for any degree spline.

Comment: This doesn't seem like an analytic solution in any reasonable sense of the word.

Comment: Well yeah, but I gathered from the above discussion that iteration is required, and no purely analytic solution exists. Anyway, I'm now realizing that I'm only computing a local minimum, which is suitable for finding the earliest closest approach for things like path planning. I'm out of my depth for the broader problem.